# nested using() and code rule CA2202

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I've the following code that warns the Code Quality rule CA2202

```
public void Deserialize(byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(ms))
        {
            this.ClientRequestId = reader.ReadUInt32();
            this.PayloadSize = reader.ReadUInt32();
            this.Payload = reader.ReadString((int)this.PayloadSize).TrimEnd('\0');
        }
    }
```

Why this happens and how can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: [CA2202: Do not dispose objects multiple times](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx)

Comment: Because BinaryReader disposes its stream internally. Personally I would ignore/exempt this warning.